# How can I show a foundation.css dropmenu by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to write a nav bar with foundation.css, but the sub-menu does not show when mouse move on.

The question is, how can I show the sub-menu of `test` in [this webpage](https://jsfiddle.net/qmvpgj5d/).

I tried to change the `visibility`, `display`, `z-index`, `left`, but nothing happend.

Comment: Please include **all** relevant HTML, CSS and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the foundation.css is not a standard css library.

Simply by adding the following js script. [Click here to see the magic](https://jsfiddle.net/yp89knqu/)

The basic idea is to change `clip` of `.dropdown` to show and hide it.

```
function drop_show(a) {
    var s = '#'+a + " ul.dropdown";
    $(s).css('clip', 'auto');
}

function drop_hide(a) {
    var s = '#'+a + " ul.dropdown";
    $(s).css('clip', 'rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px)')
}
var drop_a = $('.has-dropdown');
drop_a.each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onMouseOver", "drop_show('" + $(this).attr('id') + "');");
    $(this).attr("onMouseout", "drop_hide('" + $(this).attr('id') + "');");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/two6v954/
```

Comment: No,  I cannot change the css, the css file I'm using comes from wordpress,  not exactly foundation.css. So, I try to use jQuery to fix the mouseover event.